# Why Does LINQ Select Always Return One Row

Tags: c#, linq

Can anyone tell me why this LINQ statement is always returning one row, even though there is no matching data? How can I get the LINQ to return zero rows for no data?

```
var returnList = listProductSubAreas
.Where(o => o.ProductID == productID && o.ProductAreaID == productAreaID)
.OrderBy(o => o.ProductAreaName)
.Select(o => new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = o.SubProductArea,
                Value = o.SubProductArea
            }).DistinctBy(o => new { o.Text, o.Value }).ToList();
```

Comment: If there really isn't any data, that should indeed return 0 rows. What happens if you *just* use the `Where` call?

Comment: What about the result of the first part of the query (Where )???? is it empty ?

Comment: I just tried adding  && o.SubProductArea == "", but it still returns one row.

Comment: Im curious, how does this non existing data look like? what does the single row contain?

Comment: The count is 1. The item at position 0 is Selected=false, Text="", Value=""

Comment: where does your DistinctBy come from? MoreLINQ?

Comment: Attach a debugger and see what the values (or query) *really* is.

Comment: I added the following where clause that fixed the problem:  && o.SubProductArea.Trim().Length != 0

Comment: Can you use the Any() method on the result to determine if you have anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've put together the code you provided in an example. When placed in a Controller, it acts exactly as it should (using MoreLinq), an item count of 0 is returned.

Can you confirm this is the case, and if so, show any other code you may have used that could have affected the selection process (i.e. the search criteria values), or the initial listProductSubAreas item values.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        List<ProductSubArea> listProductSubAreas = new List<ProductSubArea>();

        int productID = 3;
        int productAreaID = 3;

        ProductSubArea psa1 = new ProductSubArea();
        psa1.ProductID = 1;
        psa1.ProductAreaID = 1;
        psa1.ProductAreaName = "Test1";
        psa1.SubProductArea = "SubTest1";

        listProductSubAreas.Add(psa1);

        ProductSubArea psa2 = new ProductSubArea();
        psa2.ProductID = 2;
        psa2.ProductAreaID = 2;
        psa2.ProductAreaName = "Test2";
        psa2.SubProductArea = "SubTest2";

        listProductSubAreas.Add(psa2);

        var returnList = listProductSubAreas
            .Where(o => o.ProductID == productID && o.ProductAreaID == productAreaID)
            .OrderBy(o => o.ProductAreaName)
            .Select(o => new SelectListItem { Text = o.SubProductArea, Value = o.SubProductArea })
            .DistinctBy(o => new { o.Text, o.Value })
            .ToList();

        int count = returnList.Count();

        return View();
    }
}

public class ProductSubArea
{
    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    public int ProductAreaID { get; set; }
    public string ProductAreaName { get; set; }
    public string SubProductArea { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I am going to mark your answer as correct. It turns out that there was some data being returned with blank strings in the SubProductArea field. The solution was to add the following code to the where clause:

&& o.SubProductArea.Trim().Length != 0

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this:

```
        var returnList = items
            .Where(o => o.ProductID == productID && o.ProductAreaID == productAreaID)
            .OrderBy(o => o.ProductAreaName)
            .Select(o => new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = o.SubProductArea,
                Value = o.SubProductArea
            }).Distinct().ToList();
```

I get zero items returned.

I think it is the DistinctBy that is your problem. 
Which implementation of it are you using??

Comment: The problem was that there was actually data being returned. I added the following where clause that fixed the problem: && o.SubProductArea.Trim().Length != 0